# How do I target an unfocused DataGrid with RoutedCommands if they are in different Prism regions?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, prism

I've been stumped with this problem for a couple weeks and I'm hoping I can get some suggestions. I have 2 Prism regions. A Toolbar region which contains a ToolbarView (ToolBarTray control) and a content region that contains a DataGridView (DataGrid control).

[image: regions]

My toolbar region has various RoutedCommands that perform commands on the DataGrid

```
<ToolBar ClipToBounds="False">
    <Button Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Undo}"
            Content="Undo"/>
    <Button Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Redo}"
            Content="Redo"/>
    <Button Command="{x:Static local:CustomDataGrid.FooCommand}"
            Content="Foo"/>
</ToolBar>
```

When my DataGrid doesn't have keyboard focus, Undo, Redo and Foo buttons will disable. When I click on the a DataGrid cell, they will re-enable. Having these buttons disable when the DataGrid loses keyboard focus can be confusing and sometimes frustrating. (Example: Deleting a row makes the DataGrid lose keyboard focus which disables all the buttons). Is there anything I can do to ensure that Undo/Redo and Foo will stay enabled and will work on the DataGrid? I've considered using IEventAggregator but I feel like that defeats the purpose of using RoutedCommands. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I've considered using IEventAggregator but I feel like that defeats the purpose of using RoutedCommands.

Exactly, and that's a good thing. Right now, how do your tests look for this setup? I reckon, there aren't any. If the tool bar's view model communicated with the data grid's view model through some code (as opposed to xaml, it can be `IEventAggregator` or some other service, or they could be the *same instance*), it would be lot easier to write a test suite.

My advice is to dump the routed commands.

Comment: I dont understand, so lets say you create your own custom control and you want to perform commands, you shouldn't implement RoutedCommands? Seems bizarre since it's pretty fundamental to custom controls

Comment: I'd wager wou're not building a custom control. Creating a custom control has nothing to do with Prism or any libraries on top of wpf. You're just creating a view for your application, which is totally fine, of course, but is the wrong place for routed commands, you want things to happen in code, so you can test them easily and automatically.

Comment: Apologies, I should've been more clear. My DataGrid **is** a custom control (that inherits from DataGrid). I have various extended ApplicationCommands such as Undo, Redo, Copy, Paste, which aren't natively implemented in Microsoft's DataGrid. I guess I can revert to IEventAggregator, but I liked being able to write less code by binding to an ApplicationCommand in my toolbar